Citations are not showing in Texmaker
I'm just trying a sample document, but the citations seem to be not working properly.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 8in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}        
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\section{Ref.~\cite{Lee:1977yc}}

In the minimal standard model with a single Higgs doublet, Ref.~\cite{Lee:1977yc} found an upper bound on the Higgs boson using the constraint from the perturbative unitarity that turned out to be $m_h < (8\pi \sqrt{2}/3 G_F)^2$, where $G_F$ is the Fermi constant.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refs_HiggsBound.bib}

\end{document}

and refs_HiggsBound.bib includes
@article{Lee:1977yc,
author = "Lee, Benjamin W. and Quigg, C. and Thacker, H. B.",
title = "{The Strength of Weak Interactions at Very High-Energies and the Higgs Boson Mass}",
reportNumber = "FERMILAB-PUB-77-022-T",
doi = "10.1103/PhysRevLett.38.883",
journal = "Phys. Rev. Lett.",
volume = "38",
pages = "883--885",
year = "1977"

}
Please help.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

Thanks for the link, I'm aware of it and have tried the compilation chain, but nothing works! The link is informative, but doesn't seem that it has solved anybody's issue!

Saying "nothing works" does not help anyone help you. If the references do not appear you will have an error message in the log, show the .log and .blg logs of latex and bibtex

the \bibliograhy command should not have .bib in the argument altough current bibtex accepts that anyway. Other than that your example runs without error and produces this output

@DavidCarlisle, I really appreciate your help.
First, there is no error message appearing, except some warnings! All texts are there after compilation except the references!
Second, I know the \bibliography shouldn't have .bib but was just trying different combination.
Third, I need to use LuaLateX for the compilation, should that be any issue ?
Lastly, there is no .log or .blg file generated in the folder where my main .tex file exists.

there will be a .blg somewhere  (the working directory from where you ran bibtex) that is not necessarily the folder with the file, if you go bibtex ../../fooo/bar/wibble/mainfile then teh blg will appear whereyou are not in the folder with mainfile.aux running lualatex on your exampel you should have exactly one warning Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):  if you get more, show your log file (again tex always writes a log)

I couldn't find .blg file anywhere! I don't know how to upload a screenshot in this comment, otherwise I would have shown that the <.bibtex> folder doesn't contain .blg file. It contains two subfoalders,  and  only.

well in that case the best guess is there is no blg as bibtex never ran, which would be consistent with no bibliography appearing.

You must be right as I see that the .bib file was last modified 5 days ago while the main tex file is updated at the time I'm running it! What should be done in that case ?

I've tried the solution provided in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037493/bibtex-not-finding-aux-file-within-texmakers-build-subdirectory], but nothing changed!

bib is your source it will just be updated when you edit it, bibtex will generate a bbl file which has the generated bibliography.  first check it works out of the editor, cd to your folder type pdflatex mainfile; bibtex mainfile; pdflatex mainfile; pdflatex mainfile`  and check you get no error, and a generate bibliography

how are you running bibtex from your editor?

I've got the solution by changing the command line for the bibtex in the Texmaker configuration. There was an extra '/build' subdirectory and after removing that .bbl file was also generated and references appeared correctly! @DavidCarlisle thanks for your help anyway, appreciate that.
